# The data in my list is being overwritten by the new data that is being entered

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, enums

Hey I'm new to Python just trying to learn and enhance my programming skills and I can't seem to understand why my output of the list is printing out wrong. 
It should print out:
`"Property Type: House"` and `"Purchase Type: purchase"`. Right after it should print out  `"Property Type: Apt"` and `"Purchase Type: rental"` but it prints the the Apt and rental twice and ignores the first pair of info that was added. Can't seem to understand why it does that. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

```
class Agent:

    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = []

    def add_new_property(self, property_type, purchase_type):
        self.prop_type = property_type
        self.pur_type = purchase_type
        self.properties.append(self)

    def print_properties(self):
        for property in self.properties:
            print("Property Type: " + property.prop_type)
            print("Purchase Type: " + property.pur_type)

a = Agent()
a.add_new_property("house", "purchase")
a.add_new_property("apt", "rental")
a.print_properties()
```

Comment: Actually try looking at your `a`. It is deeply nested: ie `a.properties[0].properties[0]….properties[0]` will still give you back `a`. This is because `a` is pointing back to itself. thus each time, you make a change to `a` a is changed rather than being appended to Note that all the pointers given are the same

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was that you were using the `class Agent` to store properties, as well as creating them, and assigning a purchase type. Separating the concerns, with each objects doing only what they should do is probably a better approach.

You probably want to have a class for Properties that encapsulates the type of property, and the type of purchase.

You also may like to separate the handling of the `Properties` from the handling of the `Agent`

Then, because you want to improve your programming skills, and you used the terms `Property type`, and `Purchase type`, I suggest that you use `Enums` to create a proper 'type' for these objects.

In the following example, you have agents that have a collection of properties.
A Property has two attributes: a type of property, and a type of transaction.

```
from enum import Enum


class PropertyType(Enum):
    HOUSE = 1, 'house' 
    APPARTMENT = 2

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class PurchaseType(Enum):
    PURCHASE = 1
    RENTAL = 2

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Property:
    """represents one property"""

    def __init__(self, property_type, purchase_type):
        self.property_type = property_type
        self.purchase_type = purchase_type

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.property_type}, {self.purchase_type}'


class Properties:
    """represents a collection of properties"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = []

    def __iter__(self):
        for ppty in self.properties:
            yield ppty

    def add_property(self, new_property):
        self.properties.append(new_property)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join('\t' + str(ppty) for ppty in self)


class Agent():
    """represents a real estate agens with his properties"""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.properties = Properties()

    def add_property(self, new_property):
        self.properties.add_property(new_property)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}: \n{str(self.properties)}'


agent_john = Agent('John')
agent_john.add_property(Property(PropertyType.HOUSE, PurchaseType.PURCHASE))
agent_john.add_property(Property(PropertyType.APPARTMENT, PurchaseType.RENTAL))
print(agent_john)
```

#### output:

```
John: 
    HOUSE, PURCHASE
    APPARTMENT, RENTAL
```

---

What is probably still missing is a collection of `Agent`

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, you will realize that you are appending the object to itself, thus we need to append the copy of the object and not itself. This ensures the pointers to the object and its copy are different. Hence after updating the object, we still maintain its previous copy

class Agent:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.properties = []

def add_new_property(self, property_type, purchase_type):
    from copy import copy
    self.prop_type = property_type
    self.pur_type = purchase_type
    self.properties.append(copy(self))

def print_properties(self):
    for property in self.properties:
        print("Property Type: " + property.prop_type, end = '\t\t')
        print("Purchase Type: " + property.pur_type)


a = Agent()
a.add_new_property("house", "purchase")
a.add_new_property("apt", "rental")
a.print_properties()

Property Type: house            Purchase Type: purchase
Property Type: apt              Purchase Type: rental
```

Answer (score -1):

Just an idea, if you use a dictionary you could trim your code down a bit, like this

```
class Agent:

    def __init__(self):
        self.props = {}

    def add_new_property(self, prop_type, buy_type):
        self.props[prop_type] =  buy_type

    def print_properties(self):
        for k, v in self.props.items():
            print(f"Property Type: {k}".ljust(20),f"Purchase Type: {v}")

a = Agent()
a.add_new_property("house", "purchase")
a.add_new_property("apt", "rental")
a.print_properties()
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 class.py
> Property Type: house Purchase Type: purchase
> Property Type: apt   Purchase Type: rental
> ```